# C# serialize json to class

Tags: c#, json, httpclient

This is my json :

```
"{\"sctoken\":\"a50395d5-571983f3-b394-4c6f-a26a-f95ae125fad6\",\"tms\":[{\"name\":\"ELTE MapCenterCache\",\"url\":\"http://cache2.smok.net.pl/cache_2015/element?s=%zoom%&x=%x%&y=%y%\"},{\"name\":\"OSM Mapnik\",\"url\":\"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/%zoom%/%x%/%y%.png\"},{\"name\":\"OSMElteMapa\",\"url\":\"http://osm.smok.net.pl/osm_tiles/%zoom%/%x%/%y%.png\"}],\"user_descr\":\"Pawel Okarmus\"}"
```

this how I convert json to class :

```
LoginResult loginResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResult>(result.ToString());


class LoginResult
{
    string sctoken { set; get; }
    List<Maps> tms { set; get; }
}

class Maps
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

and my object LoginResult is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
LoginResult loginResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result.ToString());
    public class Tm
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string sctoken { get; set; }
        public List<Tm> tms { get; set; }
        public string user_descr { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>()` does not produce a `LoginResult`. Also, a good answer explains what you changed and why.

Comment: The crux is the `public` modifier on the classes and on the properties of `Tm` (which was renamed from `Maps` for no reason, I guess because you generated it).

Comment: yes you are right. first i convert JSON string to JSON object and after that stringify that JSON object and generated class from that stringify  JSON string. @PeterB

Comment: Could you say me why I can not do this :     loginResult =  Test1(LogIncs); ?

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you make the properties and the classes all `public`, so the deserializer can find & access them:

```
public class LoginResult
{
    public string sctoken { set; get; }
    public List<Maps> tms { set; get; }
}

public class Maps
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

You are also missing the element `user_descr` but that is not essential (you can still add it, or omit it if you don't need it).

Comment: Could you say me why I can not do this :     loginResult =  Test1(LogIncs); ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `Public` in your `LoginResult` class , just put Public access modifier and it would start working (like this):

```
  class LoginResult
    {
        public string sctoken { set; get; }
        public List<Maps> tms { set; get; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you say me why I can not do this :     loginResult =  Test1(LogIncs); ?

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do here ?

Comment: When I finidh this metgod i have parametr sctoken I want to do another functiion which I use this ectoken